# How enable/disable a wxRadioBox item using a mouse left double click

Tags: windows, mouseevent, wxwidgets

Under wxWidgets 2.8 I want to enable or disable a **wxRadioBox** item using a mouse left double click on the label which identify the item.
To this end I plan to use the **GetItemFromPoint** to identify the item.

The problem is that I cant't able to capture the mouse event when do a double click over the wxRadioBox, neither on the parent panel, nor using a derived class of wxRadioBox.

A sample code

in .h file

```
class PrinterRadioBox: public wxRadioBox
{
  public:
  PrinterRadioBox(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString& label, const wxPoint& point, const wxSize& size, int n, const wxString choices[], int majorDimension, long style, const wxValidator& validator, const wxString& name)
    : wxRadioBox(parent,id, label, point, size, n, choices, majorDimension, style, validator, name)
{                           
}
PrinterRadioBox(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString& label, const wxPoint& point, const wxSize& size, const wxArrayString& choices, int majorDimension = 0, long style = wxRA_SPECIFY_COLS, const wxValidator& validator = wxDefaultValidator, const wxString& name = "radioBox")
    : wxRadioBox(parent, id, label, point, size, choices, majorDimension, style, validator, name)
{
}

  void OnLeftDClick(wxMouseEvent& event);
 private:   
   DECLARE_NO_COPY_CLASS(PrinterRadioBox)
   DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};
```

in .cpp file

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(PrinterRadioBox, wxRadioBox)
    EVT_LEFT_DCLICK(PrinterRadioBox::OnLeftDClick)        
END_EVENT_TABLE()

void PrinterRadioBox::OnLeftDClick(wxMouseEvent& event)
{                          
  wxMessageBox("here radio box");
  event.Skip();     
}
```

How can I enable or disable a single item (element) of a wxRadioBox by selecting it with a double click?

Comment: `EVT_LEFT_DCLICK` is not working for `wxRadioBox`?

Comment: @catalin unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: @famedoro, can you post some code? In particular - how do you catch the event and what the event handler look like?

Comment: Show some code. Maybe you are doing it wrong. "doesn't work" is too vague.

Answer (score 1):

At least in wxMSW, `wxRadioBox` is a composite native control consisting of a box and the buttons inside it and you're going to have problems catching events from those. If you really need to do this, consider using individual `wxRadioButton`s instead.

I also believe `wxRadioBox` implementation has changed since 2.8 (hard to remember all the details for 10+ year old version...), so you really should switch to a more recent wx version.